# Multiple Select and Join with LINQ and Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I do this `query` using `LINQ and LAMBDA` ?

**QUERY**

```
Select san_negocio.imovel_id
      ,san_negocio.negocio_id
      ,san_imovel.credenciada_id
      ,san_proposta.proposta_id
      ,san_proposta.credenciada_id
  from san_negocio
  join san_proposta
    on san_negocio.imovel_id = san_proposta.imovel_id
  join san_imovel
    on san_negocio.imovel_id = san_imovel.imovel_id
 where san_negocio.credenciadacaptadora_id is null
   and san_negocio.credenciadavendedora_id is null
   and san_proposta.statusproposta_id = 2
```

**I've tried:**

```
var objetos = db.San_Negocio.Join(db.San_Proposta, a => a.Imovel_Id, b => b.Imovel_Id, (a, b) => new { San_Negocio = a, San_Proposta = b })                
    .Join(db.San_Imovel, a => a.San_Negocio.Imovel_Id, c => c.Imovel_Id, (a, c) => new { San_Negocio = a, San_Imovel = c })
    .Where(a => a.San_Negocio.San_Negocio.CredenciadaCaptadora_Id == null && a.San_Negocio.San_Negocio.CredenciadaVendedora_Id == null)
    .Select(a => new { a.San_Negocio.San_Negocio.Negocio_Id, 
            a.San_Negocio.San_Negocio.Imovel_Id, 
            a.San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id });
```

My doubt is in my `Select`. How can I call my `San_Proposta` table ?

Comment: Why does it need to be done using a lambda? That version looks absolutely awful to understand.

Comment: Can be without lambda. This is because I would like to understand better how lambda work with that.

Comment: I think it might be better if you first read some samples about linq code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b#nested and then decide what method you want to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proper linq statement:

```
from neg in db.san_negocio
join prop in san_proposta
    on neg.imovel.id equals prop.imovel_id
join imo in san_imovel
    on neg.imovel_id = imo.imovel_id
where neg.credenciadacaptadora_id == null && 
    neg.credenciadavendedora_id == null &&
    prop.statusproposta_id == 2
select new {
    ImovelID = neg.imovel_id,
    NegocioID = neg.negocio_id,
    Imo_CredenciadaID = imo.credenciada_id,
    PropostaID = prop.proposta_id
    Prop_CredenciadaID = prop.credenciada_id
};
```

This will create an IQueryable of anonymous objects with the listed properties above.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. But how it works using lambda expression ?

Answer (score 6):

You are hiding `San_Proposta` within a field called `San_Negocio`, so calling `a.San_Negocio.San_Proposta` will access it, but I recommend writing your joins in a way that fields aren't nested, like this:

```
var objetos = db.San_Negocio
    .Join(db.San_Proposta, 
          a => a.Imovel_Id,
          b => b.Imovel_Id, 
          (a, b) => new { San_Negocio = a, San_Proposta = b })                
    .Join(db.San_Imovel, 
          a => a.San_Negocio.Imovel_Id,
          c => c.Imovel_Id,
          (a, c) => new { a.San_Negocio, a.San_Proposta, San_Imovel = c })
    .Where(a => a.San_Negocio.CredenciadaCaptadora_Id == null && 
                a.San_Negocio.CredenciadaVendedora_Id == null)
    .Select(a => new
                 {
                     a.San_Negocio.Negocio_Id, 
                     a.San_Negocio.Imovel_Id,
                     a.San_Proposta.San_Proposta_Id, 
                     a.San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id
                 });
```

Comment: Thank you!! And by the way. THIS IS REAL LINQ. Not that other stuff.

Comment: Both are LINQ, Joel is using the Linq Query syntax and Risky is using the Lambda syntax.